# Does integrated graphics slow down CPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu

I always thought the CPU performs two tasks so when you disable the onboard graphics the CPU will be faster (because it has less work to do). But since I know that graphics calculation differs very much from normal CPU operations I'm no longer sure about this.

The normal CPU uses the 64-bit instruction set (on a 64-bit system). Graphics calculation is about matrices, 3D and so on.

So when you have a CPU with integrated graphics:

- Is it like one processor performing two tasks or is it two processors on one chip (each performing its task simultaneously)?
- Will the CPU be faster if you disable the integrated graphics and use a dedicated graphics card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrated graphics is a separate chip from the CPU, but it is in the same package.

As such the GPU does not "use" CPU time to work.

That does not mean that the integrated GPU *doesn't* slow the CPU down slightly though. The integrated GPU uses the same memory as your CPU, as a result graphical tasks can take bandwidth from the CPU and cause some level of contention.

Given the massive bandwidth of modern memory the penalty will, for tasks such as desktop composition and "normal" programs, be of the order of a few percent of memory bandwidth. Small enough that you will almost certainly not notice. The Windows desktop compositor is quite efficient and only updates when graphics has changed leaving a smaller amount of ongoing bandwidth required for the GPU to put the screen out to your monitor.

For gaming and 3D modelling and other graphically intensive applications there may be a lot more bandwidth used by the GPU to deal with textures, shader programs, geometry and so on over several passes. That would use a lot more bandwidth and you will reach a point where your CPU and GPU are fighting over bandwidth to do all the work to show graphics and handle all the other system tasks. That would be where you definitely want to switch to dedicated graphics. Light games might be fine though.

Disabling integrated graphics and using a dedicated card will remove system memory contention.

Answer (score 1):

**Large resolution displays** connected to integrated to **integrated GPUs** sap **performance *constantly***.

Here is how.

Any GPU constantly sends frames to the connected monitor. The picture is held in GPU framebuffer and send over and over again at the monitor refresh rate.

With integrated GPUs the framebuffer is located in system memory. The buffers itself is not big part of that memory (32MB for UHD display).
However, it is sent to the monitor 60 times a second.

```
32 [MB/frame] * [60 frames/s] = 2 [GB/s]
```

Is this a lot? How does having a UHD monitor with iGPU and some affect the system performance?

A mid range laptop 9th Gen might have a single DDR4-3600 RAM module with total 25.6GB/s bandwidth.

Therefore 2GB/s + some overheads might easily reach 10% of the system performance.
This will affects some usecases not all but it can easily become system bottleneck.

Imagine 2 UHD monitors and it makes 20%. Throw in an constantly refreshing browser window or a zoom call, that would push it over 40%. Dear to do both at once.
And it is not as easy as adding those percentages as RAM latency is in a way similar to mechanical disks (where you'd better not copy multiple files at once).

Such impact is observable on a fairly modern 9th Gen Intel laptop with integrated GPU and single RAM module - drastically lower user perceived responsiveness. Disconnecting one 4k monitor or lowering resolution considerably the problem.

1080p resolution desktops would have much smaller impact.
Also note that having 2 RAM modules significantly reduces the problem (as this doubles overall RAM bandwidth), and recent gen systems have RAM modules with much higher bandwidth to start with.

Following wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology some Intel Iris iGPUs had embedder RAM (eDRAM). This has been ditched in 10th Gen.

Update: Recent Ryzen 5xxx and later processors have VRAM on the chip, which mitigates the problem.

Comment: iGPU have a maximum amount of memory that can be hardware reserved. Your not going to be able to reserve 40% of your memory. Your zoom statement is factually false.

Comment: @Ramhound It looks like misunderstanding. I am not talking about amount of memory used here. I am talking about memory bandwidth: the rate at which data is pulled from memory module.
Entire content of the screen is sent by graphic hardware to the monitor 60 times every second. For 4K/UHD it is 32MB/frame*60frames/s=~2GB/s. That is the minimum if displayed frame is still. 2GB is quite a lot if the total bandwidth is 25.6GB/s.

Comment: You wrote on the answer "32GB for UHD display" and the same on the math but I'm guessing you mean 32MB there?

Comment: @Daniel thanks,fixed