# Will my CPU's Integrated graphics try doing work while my dedicated GPU is also working?

Tags: cpu, gpu, integrated-graphics

The following questions have answers that contradict each other, and as a consequence, I have become confused.

1. **[Integrated graphics only or integrated + dedicated](https://superuser.com/questions/1620619/integrated-graphics-only-or-integrated-dedicated)**
2. **[Does integrated graphics slow down CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/1533988/does-integrated-graphics-slow-down-cpu)**

One question's answer claims that a CPU w/ integrated graphics, will not only run & work at the same time as the GPU, but it will fight over bandwidth with the GPU. If this is true, it sounds advantagous, to those who use a dedicated GPU, to use a CPU without integrated graphics.

Conversely, the other Q&A's answer says that they don't work at the same time, its either one or the other, thus the integrated graphics won't hinder preformance if your using a GPU. Which, if this is true, means that the only reason to not buy an intel "f" cpu (like the 12700KF, which I am considering) is to save 5 bucks. This doesn't make sense to me.

I am asking because I want to know why CPUs are sometimes offered without integrated graphics. It would make far more sense if there was a $25 + price difference, but there is only a $5 differnce in most cases. the [12th Generation Intel CPU I am considering](https://www.newegg.com/intel-core-i7-12700kf-core-i7-12th-gen/p/N82E16819118345?Item=9SIA24GGNF9587) is currently only $5 less than the version w/ graphics.

In a nutshell I would like to know what a system works like when it has a GPU & integrated graphics, when it has only integrated graphics, and when it has only a dedicated GPU?

Comment: This also depends on the motherboard, but the question is much too general. (If economizing on power is a consideration, don't buy a CPU without integrated graphics.)

Comment: Integrated graphics saves on power even if I have a GPU installed too?

Comment: Yes, the discrete GPU doesn't take much power when not in use. The integrated GPU shares the CPU power much more efficiently.